# Print objects in Python

Tags: python, object, methods, printing

I am trying to print multiple occurences of an object to show the name that is associated with the object. This i what i currently get. How can i get the information from each of the objects? Below is what i get and my code for the method that creates this.

```
def get_rarest_card(self):

    card_rarities = Counter(card.rarity for card in self.cardlist if card.rarity !="Basic Land")
    rarity = min(card_rarities, key=lambda card: card_rarities[card])  # Effectively an argmin
    return [card for card in self.cardlist if card.rarity == rarity]
```

The output is:

```
[<__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4d65c0>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4d6b38>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4d9c88>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4d2048>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b566208>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b566668>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4d9780>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4e80b8>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4f4080>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4f4be0>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4f4cc0>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b4f47b8>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b5002e8>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b500e48>,
 <__main__.MagicCard at 0x10b500d30>]
```

Comment: Try implementing the  $__repr__ $ metaclass function inside the class.

Comment: How would you do that? Im new to OOP in Python and havent worked with that

Comment: In the MagicCard object make a function called 
    __repr__
 It's the same kind of function as 
    __init__

Would look something like this:
    def MagicCard():
        def __repr__(self):
           return #String REPResentation of MagicCard

Comment: I added in def __repr__ into my Magic Card object and when i ran the call of the object i get this error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object